# Using components on pages, layout always choosing default. Can not chose another layout

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I have a problem of nuxt.js
When I try using components in some pages, and layout is 'something' (layout:'something').
But layout always applied default.
Is this a nuxt bug? or there some rules about it?

```
// pages/main.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <something />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import something from "@/components/something.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    something
  },
  layout: 'a'
};
</script>
```

.
.
.

```
// layouts/a.vue
<template>
  <v-app class="dark">
    <nuxt/>
  </v-app>
</template>
<style scoped>
.dark {
  background:black;
}
</style>
```

.
.
.

```
// components/something.vue
<template>
  <div>
  Hello
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: could you show us your `something` layout and where you have putted it?

Comment: Don't you have any error in console ?

Comment: Thankyou all wait a minutes, I bring it.

Comment: You want `something` to be layout or `a`?

Comment: And layout must be in `layouts` folder

Comment: @BeHappy Sorry I made a miss. thats layouts

Comment: @BeHappy I want apply layout "a" tomain.vue

Comment: Do you have error in console?

Comment: @BeHappy I checkd error just now. But console has no error...

Comment: And avoid components property, layout applied "a"... hmm

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't apply? :)

Comment: Change a name to something like `APage` and then : `layout: 'APage'`

Comment: Tried 'APage'. But nothing change... But tried 'default.vue' to 'BPage'(Totally, There are 'Apage' and 'BPage' on layouts dir), I found what 'APage' showing in a moment (like a 0.0001sec), then show 'An error occurred'.

Comment: So what was error?

Comment: Sorry I don't know... This error message shown as HTML. And console says no error...

Comment: You can add image or check terminal.

Comment: I'm sorry. Try to solve it myself... Thankyou for you help!! I will reply when it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Add some paragraph to your layout and check out if its applied:

```
<template>
  <v-app class="dark">
    <p>Hello from layout</p>
    <nuxt/>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Comment: Thansks. But Certainly found not applied (つ﹏<)･ﾟ｡

Comment: check for typos, error, and repeat the documentation maybe you did something wrong

Comment: Yes...Maybe my code is something wrong,,,, I'll check that. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you not suppose to import the v-app component to your layout and then export it?

```
<script>
  import VApp from "@/components/../..

  export default {
  components: {
    VApp
  }
</script>
```

Of course, depending of the location of your v-app component